# Azure Tables or SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I am at the planning stage of a web application that will be hosted in Azure with ASP.NET for the web site and Silverlight within the site for a rich user experience. Should I use Azure Tables or SQL Azure for storing my application data?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Azure Table Storage appears to be less expensive than SQL Azure. It is also more highly scalable than SQL Azure.

SQL Azure is easier to work with if you've been doing a lot of relational database work. If you were porting an application that was already using a SQL database, then moving it to SQL Azure would be the obvious choice, but that's the only situation where I would recommend it.

The main limitation on Azure Tables is the lack of secondary indexes. This was announced at PDC '09 and is currently listed as coming soon, but there hasn't been any time-frame announcement. (See http://windowsazure.uservoice.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/396314-support-secondary-indexes?ref=title)

I've seen the proposed use of a hybrid system where you use table and blob storage for the bulk of your data, but use SQL Azure for indexes, searching and filtering. However, I haven't had a chance to try that solution yet myself.

Once the secondary indexes are added to table storage, it will essentially be a cloud based [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) system and will be much more useful than it is now.

Comment: Let's hope they announce this at Build 2014.

Comment: As stated in my answer, this was announced at PDC (what they used to call Build) in 2009! I stopped holding my breath a few years ago. An announcement at Build 2014 would be laughable. They just need to ship the feature. Azure Tables could have been a contender.

Answer (score 13):

Despite similar names SQL Azure Tables and Table Storage have very little in common.

Here are a two links that might help you:

- [Table Storage, a 100x cost factor](http://vermorel.com/journal/2009/9/17/table-storage-or-the-100x-cost-factor.html)
- [Fat Entities on Table Storage](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/wiki/FatEntities)

Basically, the first question should wonder about is *Does my app really need to scale?* If not, then go for SQL Azure.

Answer (score 8):

For those trying to decide between the two options, be sure to factor reporting requirements into the equation.  [SQL Azure Reporting](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazure/reporting.aspx) and other reporting products support SQL Azure out of the box.  If you need to generate complex or flexible reports, you'll probably want to avoid Table Storage.

Answer (score 4):

Azure tables are cheaper, simpler and scale better than SQL Azure. SQL Azure is a managed SQL environment, multi-tenant in nature, so you should analyze if your performance requirements are fit for SQL Azure. A premium version of SQL Azure has been announced and is in preview as of this writing (see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn369873.aspx)).

I think the decisive factors to decide between SQL Azure and Azure tables are the following:

- Do you need to do complex joins and use secondary indexes? If yes, SQL Azure is the best option.
- Do you need stored procedures? If yes, SQL Azure.
- Do you need auto-scaling capabilities? Azure tables is the best option.
- Rows within an Azure table cannot exceed 4MB in size. If you need to store large data within a row, it is better to store it in blob storage and reference the blob's URI in the table row.
- Do you need to store massive amounts of semi-structured data? If yes, Azure tables are advantageous.

Although Azure tables are tremendously beneficial in terms of simplicity and cost, there are some limitations that need to be taken into account. Please see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx) for some initial guidance.

Answer (score 3):

One other consideration is latency. There used to be a site that Microsoft ran with microbenchmarks on throughput and latency of various object sizes with table store and SQL Azure.  Since that site's no longer available, I'll just give you a rough approximation from what I recall. Table store tends to have much higher throughput than SQL Azure. SQL Azure tends to have lower latency (by as much as 1/5th).

It's already been mentioned that table store is easy to scale. However, SQL Azure can scale as well with [Federations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597452.aspx). Note that Federations (effectively [sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29)) adds a lot of complexity to your application. I'm also not sure how much Federations affects performance, but I imagine there's some overhead.

If business continuity is a priority, consider that with Azure Storage [you get cheap geo-replication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/09/15/introducing-geo-replication-for-windows-azure-storage.aspx) by default. With SQL Azure, you can accomplish something similar but with more effort with [SQL Data Sync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667320). Note that SQL Data Sync also incurs performance overhead since it requires triggers on all of your tables to watch for data changes.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but still a very valid one, so I'm adding my reply to it.

CoderDennis and others have pointed out some of the facts - Azure Tables is cheaper, and Azure Tables can be much larger, more efficient etc. If you are 100% sure you will stick with Azure, go with Tables.

However this assumes you have already decided on Azure. By using Azure Tables, you are locking yourself into the Azure platform. It means writing code very specific to Azure Tables that is not just going to port over to Amazon, you will have to rewrite those areas of your code. On the other hand programming for a SQL database with LINQ will port over much more easily to another cloud service.

This may not be an issue if you've already decided on your cloud platform.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at Azure Cache in combination with Azure Table. Table alone has 200-300ms latencies, with occasional spikes higher, which can significantly slow down response times / UI interactivity. Cache + Table seems to be a winning combination, for me.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, I want to talk about how to decide with logic choose SQL Table and which need to use Azure Table.

As we know SQL Table is a relational database engine. but if you have a big data in one table the SQL Table is not applicable, because SQL query get big data is slow.

At this time you can choose Azure Table, the Azure Table query is so fast then SQL Table for big data, for example, in our website, someone subscribed many articles, we make the article as feed to user, every user have a copy of article title and description, so in the article table there are lots of data, if we use SQL Table, each query execution maybe take more than 30 seconds. But in Azure Table get users article feed by PartitionKey and RowKey is so fast.

From this example you may know how to choose between in SQL Table and Azure Table.

Comment: Sounds like you should have added some indexes to your SQL Tables.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether we are going to end up with some "vendor independent" cloud api libraries in due course?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have first to define what your application usage funnels are. Will your data model be subjected to frequent changes or it is a stable one? You have to be able to perform ultra fast inserts and reads are not so complicated? Do you need advance google like search? Storing BLOBS?

Those are the questions (and not only) that you have to ask and answer yourself in order to decide if you are more likely going to use NoSql or SQL approach in storing your data.

Please consider that both approaches can easily coexist and can be extended with BLOB storage as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both Azure Tables and SQL Azure are two different beasts.Both are meant for different scenarios, one con to azure table is that you cannot move from azure to any other platform, unless you write providers in your code that can handle such shifts.